# dial `unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied` hyperleadger fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to instantiate the chaincode using

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n skynetchaincode -v v1 -c '{"Args":[""]}'
```

but geeting the following error.

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.org1.example.com-skynetchaincode-v1: dial unix `/host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

Solutions I tried.

```
1 Added  to peer and cli env 
   - USERNAME=$USER
   - USER_ID=1000
   - GROUP_ID=999
   - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock  
2.  chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
    srwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug 12 18:02 /var/run/docker.sock
3.  sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
4.  sudo systemctl restart docker
```

that is supposed to create a separate running docker container with installed chaincode in that but its showing access denied error

```
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-skynetchaincode-v1
```

````
fabric version 1.4  
docker Client:  
Version:         1.13.1  
 API version:     1.26  
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-96.gitb2f74b2.el7.x86_64  
 Go version:      go1.10.8  ```
````

Comment: Are you running the peer directly on your host system?

Comment: no, i have used `docker exec -it bash cli`. and used then above command.